# A question about Navier-Stokes

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces

Can Navier-Stokes equations be represented in the form

$\mathbf{x}'(t) = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}(t))$ where values of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{F}$ lie in some normed vector spaces over field $\mathbb{R}$?

Informally: Can Navier-Stokes equations be considered as equations on normed spaces over field $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, but the vector space will be infinite dimensional (space of functions of some sort). You can then hide all terms such as $\nabla$ into $F$: only the time derivative will remain on the left. I doubt that there is a finite-dimensional ODE reformulation.

Comment: That it is a vector space is obvious. I ask whether this can be considered as a *normed* vector space

Comment: @PeterFranek It is quite clear that this is infinite dimensional. This is not my question

Comment: Yes, of course, usually people consider various Sobolev functions spaces (as functions of space only). (Btw why is it clear it cannot be finite-dim-reformulated?)

Comment: @PeterFranek Because a finite set of real numbers does not contain enough information to represent moving fluid

Answer (score 1):

The Navier Stokes equation is a partial differential equation which involves unknowns that depends on time $t$ and 3D space vector $x$, so if you want to write Navier-Stokes equation explicitly you can write it as a system of 3 PDEs supplemented with another equation which is the conservation of mass equation. But, it still a Partial differential equation so if you want to get the form:
$$x'(t)=F(t,x(t)),$$
which is a differential equation you have first to use an approximation method. Methods like these are many, they aim to approximate a Partial differential equation by a differential equation in order to use the classic theory of differential equations, precisely the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem to establish a result of existence and uniqueness. So the answer of your question is yes. You can write the Navier-Stokes equation in the form $$u'(t)=F(t,u(t)).$$